# New to the Ubuntu Game any one want to help me with an AMD install?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, ati

I guess this may be annoying to some, but if you would like to help. I am definitely not to proud to beg.

Specs are as follows:

- Amd A4 4000 3.0ghz APU
- Gigabyte F2A55M-HD2 dual bios board.
- Dirt cheap micro-atx case (surpassingly slick looking though).
- Power supply is a 300watt silver stone yada yada sfx type blah.
- 64GB SSD ADATA/160 gb 7,200(was in my old macbook).

I had 13.10 semi working internet connected and all, but after trying to update through the terminal, I couldn't connect to the net again.

I haven't built a machine for linux before, my jobs have supplied me with Macs so this is all relatively new stuff for me to learn, so far I love it but I am certainly going to need to spend a lot of time with prophet google....

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to build Ubuntu, you just download it from [here](http://ubuntu.com/download) and create a LiveCD or Live USB. Then, boot from it and the installation steps are on screen.

Comment: I was referring to my hardware build. I did install 12.04....Not nearly as pretty as the initial 13.10 install I did but, damn it is easy and stable in comparison.